# not able to scale the roi in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, mediapipe

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    _, im0 = cap.read()
    showCrosshair = False
    fromCenter = False
    r = cv2.selectROI("Image", im0, fromCenter, showCrosshair)
    break

mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
hands = mpHands.Hands(static_image_mode=False,
                      max_num_hands=2,
                      min_detection_confidence=0.5,
                      min_tracking_confidence=0.5)
mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
pTime = 0
cTime = 0
while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    img = cv2.rectangle(img,(r[0],r[1]),(r[2],r[3]),(0,255,0),5)
    #imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = hands.process(img)
    print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)
    if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
        for handLms in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for id, lm in enumerate(handLms.landmark):
                print(id,lm)
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x *w), int(lm.y*h)
                cv2.circle(img, (cx,cy), 3, (255,0,255), cv2.FILLED)

            mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms, mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)

    cTime = time.time()
    fps = 1/(cTime-pTime)
    pTime = cTime
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF  == 27:
      break
    cv2.putText(img,str(int(fps)), (10,70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (255,0,255), 3)
    cv2.imshow("ThumbsDown", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

I am trying to build a program that detects hand movements in a selected region of interest, but the rectangular selection I perform does works, or it gets unscaled.
The hand detection also starts working randomly at a few points.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you share some images of what is going wrong and what you want?

Comment: thanks a lot sir , but the problem is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the question was solved
this is the code :

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry import polygon
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    _, im0 = cap.read()
    showCrosshair = False
    fromCenter = False
    r = cv2.selectROI("ThumbsDown", im0, fromCenter, showCrosshair)
    break

mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
hands = mpHands.Hands(static_image_mode=False,
                      max_num_hands=2,
                      min_detection_confidence=0.5,
                      min_tracking_confidence=0.5)
mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
x=int(r[0])
y=int(r[1])
w=int(r[2])
h=int(r[3])
a= (x,y)
b= (x,y+h)
c= (x+w,y+h)
d= (x+w,y)
points_cord=(a,b,c,d)
points=Polygon(points_cord)
pTime = 0
cTime = 0
while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    rect_img = imgRGB[int(r[1]):int(r[1]+r[3]), int(r[0]):int(r[0]+r[2])]
    results = hands.process(rect_img) 
    print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)
    if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
        for handLms in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for id, lm in enumerate(handLms.landmark):
                print(id,lm)
                h, w, c = rect_img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x *w), int(lm.y*h)
                cv2.circle(rect_img, (cx,cy), 3, (255,0,255), cv2.FILLED)
                cv2.putText(img,str("Hands-Detected"), (120,70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (252,0,0), 3)
                cv2.rectangle(img,(int(r[0]),int(r[1]+r[3])),(int(r[0]+r[2]),int(r[1])),255,3)
                cv2.rectangle(img,b,d,(25,255,231),3)
                if((cx or cy)!=0):
                    cp=Point(cx,cy)
                    if(points.contains(cp)):
                        cv2.putText(img,str("TEST"), (300,200), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (25,255,231), 3)


            mpDraw.draw_landmarks(rect_img, handLms, mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
            img[int(r[1]):int(r[1]+r[3]), int(r[0]):int(r[0]+r[2])] =rect_img        
    cv2.rectangle(img,b,d,(25,255,231),3)
    cTime = time.time()
    fps = 1/(cTime-pTime)
    pTime = cTime
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF  == 27:
      break
    cv2.putText(img,str(int(fps)), (10,70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (25,255,231), 3)
    cv2.namedWindow("ThumbsDown", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow("ThumbsDown", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Kindly explain what changes you have made to solve your issue.

Comment: @ASLAN ok sir, I added a new answer

Answer (score 0):

firstly, I was not sending the correct inputs in the previous code to the inbuilt cv2.rectangle function.

```
x=int(r[0]) 
y=int(r[1]) 
w=int(r[2]) 
h=int(r[3])
```

this is the part where I rearranged the coordinates according to the cv2.rectangle function,and its data members. rect_img = `imgRGB[int(r[1]):int(r[1]+r[3]), int(r[0]):int(r[0]+r[2])]`
in this line, we not only need x,y, but width and height.

Secondly, I was not calling the correct frame to construct the rectangle on, `rect_img = imgRGB[int(r[1]):int(r[1]+r[3]), int(r[0]):int(r[0]+r[2])]`
this is the area selected(ROI),

```
img[int(r[1]):int(r[1]+r[3]), int(r[0]):int(r[0]+r[2])] =rect_img
```

then we merge the selected frame, to the original output frame.

Comment: @ASLAN done sir, please have a look, I hope it does the work